# Problem querying MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have this project I am working on, I have a table schema, see below

```
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| codeId | int(15)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code   | varchar(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status | varchar(5) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table is used for authorizations of codes, however some people send codes like `dsfffMUBBDG345qwewqe` for authorization, please note the capitalized part. In the code column there is a code `MUBBDG345`. I need to be able to check from the table if any combination of 9 characters the codes sent matches any of the codes in the db.

I have tried using this query but i just does not work.

```
select code, codeId, status from authCodes where 'dsfffMUBBDG345qwewqe' like code;
```

Is this even possible with a mysql query only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use

```
SELECT code, codeId, status
FROM authCodes
WHERE 'dsfffMUBBDG345qwewqe' LIKE CONCAT('%', code, '%')
```

Comment: Funny thing is I had to do something nearly identical to this a few days ago and came up with basically the same solution. Can't believe I forgot about it

Comment: tried that but I am getting ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+code+'%'' at line 1